# read output from a class executed as a process

Tags: java, process

I am using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(test.class) to create a process and launch a test.class file.

test.class:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doReturn();
    }

    public static String doReturn() {
        System.out.println("printed output");
        return "returned output";
    }
}
```

in the Java application launching this process, I'd like to retrieve the output of this test.class

The code I use looks like:

```
Process proc = null;
String[] cmd = { "java", "test"};
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This snippet of code does not work: nothing is printed and I get an Exitvalue of 1 for my process.

=> How should I modify it (and / or modify test.class) to return "printed output" to my java application?
=> Is it possible to return "returned output" as well?

(I am new to Java so could you please be very detailed in your answers! Thx!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you want to do but try to remove the .class

```
String[] cmd = { "java", "test"};
```

Comment: ;) On the other hand, be careful with process' path. Try to put the absolute path to java.

Comment: you were right! Damn... it was a mistake in the path of test.class

Answer (score 0):

Try the commons exec library. It simplifies a lot of code that otherwise you would have to write. You will need to capture the inputstream from the process on another thread. There are issues in doing it on the same thread.. Some info here:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

And the commons exec library here:
http://commons.apache.org/exec/